# Why does my LINQ query in Xamarin.Forms show less than expected content?

Tags: c#, azure, xamarin, xamarin.forms

Good afternoon, I am struggling with an issue that I have been attempting to fix for around a month now.

I am creating an application that utilizes the GTFS of a transit service (TTC) to show off routes and maps in a .NET MAUI (formerly Xamarin.Forms) application.

My issue revolves around my joining of the lists in one LINQ query. I have included a pastebin of the relevant code causing the issue. It seems to me that whenever I join the lists, I lose majority of the routes I am trying to recieve. When I use Distinct(), I end up with only 17 routes  rather than the 200+ I should be seeing.

[PasteBin Link](https://pastebin.com/AkAV9Wtb)
[Example of GTFS Layout (Paste Bin)](https://pastebin.com/qU0yPLXx)

The list declaration:
`GTFS_List full_ttc_list = new GTFS_List();`

I have tried only joining the trips and stopTimes, and that did not work, so im not exactly sure where to go from here, some help and guidance would be extremely appreciated!

These .txt's are close to 120,000 per text file, my idea is that it might be clogging the memory, so perhaps running it on a Azure WebApps might help? I am using Azure to request the HTTPs of these TTC text files.

Just tried a function within my other Azure WebApp, and then requesting the HTTP still has the same issue. Not sure what is causing it anymore, or if my LINQ query is incorrect

Comment: Not too sure since you haven't included the c# code but Im guessing it might be  because you have properties in the models you're reading into that should be defined as nullable and you haven't ie. string column_name -> string? column_name

Comment: Please read [ask] before posting.  If you want help please post the relevant code.

Comment: At first glance I don't like your hash code functions. Seeing that it's something that distinct uses, it could explain the small number of results. Try to change those with something that doesn't use addition and that you actually understand.